# Insert output data to database of an web page

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i have a output page of the following php code..

```
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

      // get DOM from URL or file

      $html = file_get_html('http://www.wine-searcher.com/merchant/852');

      $data=$html->find('td.firstcell');
      echo "Country             :". $data[0].'<br />';

      echo "Email               :".$data[2].'<br />';

      echo "Postal Address      :".$data[3].'<br />';

      echo "Permanent Address   :".$data[4].'<br />';

      echo "Contact             :".$data[10].'<br />';
```

the output value of the script is to be inserted in to the database like MySQL.
for that i try something like that..

```
<?php

// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents

include('../simple_html_dom.php');

      // get DOM from URL or file

      $html = file_get_html('http://www.wine-searcher.com/merchant/852');

      $data=$html->find('td.firstcell');
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
      if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

      // Create database
      if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE nt_usawine",$con))
        {
        echo "Database created";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
        }

      // Create table
      mysql_select_db("nt_usawine", $con);
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons
      (
      FirstName varchar(15),
      LastName varchar(15),
      Age int
      )";
      // Execute query
      mysql_query($sql,$con);
      $foo= $data[2];
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
      VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin', $foo)");
      mysql_close($con);


      echo "Country             :". $data[0].'<br />';

      echo "Email               :".$data[2].'<br />';

      echo "Postal Address      :".$data[3].'<br />';

      echo "Permanent Address   :".$data[4].'<br />';

      echo "Contact             :".$data[10].'<br />';
```

but still i cant get the table in the database with my data inserted. what is the right way to save the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug this by using mysql_error ?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
          VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin', $foo)";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'There is an error : ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'The query was : ' . $query;
    die($message);
}
```

If you have an SQL error this would be very usefull.

By the way have you seen the only once time you don't do mysql_query( [...], $con) it the once which should add datas ?

And is it normal that you create a database and a table each time ? (don't know what you really want to do)

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_query();` function allows you to run a query. Using the `INSERT` syntax you can insert data.

Example:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')");
```

Currently, what I'm seeing you wish to insert the country, email, postal address, permanent address and contact even though you create a table that can hold the data `firstname`, `lastname` and `age`...

No offence, but if you're already stuck there, this is not the right place to post your question. You need to search some tutorials before you even consider asking. SQL queries are well documented and can be found all over the web.

Either way, I'm too kind to leave this question unanswered.

I advice to create your database and table in PhpMyAdmin, rather creating a new one in your script. It's rather inefficient.

```
<?php
// this is where you login to your database
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

// select your EXISTING database you created. Usually there's a single database linked to your website
mysql_select_db('database_name', $connection);

// inserting data into table
$success = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` (`country`, `email`, `postaladdr`, `permanentaddr`, `contact`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[10])."')");

// check if insert was successful
if($success) {
    echo 'data inserted';
} else {
    echo 'Something went wrong: ' . mysql_error();
}

// closing database
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Now all you have to do is change the login data, change the `database_name`, create the actual table and change the `table_name` in the script.

This is one of the first things you learn when starting with running SQL queries, so I higly suggest to learn more: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

If everything I said didn't make any sense, you should click the link above.